# Tenho um app que usa menu de abas, uma com produtos e outra com promoções como poderia implementar uma busca neste tipo de menu?

Tags: android, menu

Tenho um app que usa menu de abas como na imagem, uma com produtos e outra com promoções como poderia implementar uma busca neste tipo de menu com abas diferentes?

[image: MENU ABAS]

Comment: A busca vai ser por todos os produtos, independente do tipo?

Comment: Uma busca somente pelo nome do produto um especie de filtro, a dúvida é se ao trocar de aba mudaria a pesquisa caso colocasse uma busca na actionbar